# Putting emacs .org file options in .emacs file

Tags: org-mode, init-file, template

I use  a template for my work. It contains following options. Can I put those in .emacs file.

```
#+OPTIONS: num:nil; p:t 
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil 
#+LATEXCLASS_OPTIONS: {10pt} 
#+LATEX_HEADER: \pagenumbering{}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[a4paper, top=42mm, right=2cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry} 
#+TITLE:
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you are expecting as not in .emacs file, but in another Org file, the solution I use for a long time is to use [#+SETUPFILE:](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html)

In your .org files:

```
#+SETUPFILE: path_to_your_setup/setupFile.org
#+TITLE: My Org document
```

In the `path_to_your_setup/` directory (your project root for instance),  my `setupFile.org` is:

```
#+OPTIONS: H:3 toc:t num:t \n:nil ::t |:t ^:nil -:t f:t *:t tex:t d:t tags:not-in-toc
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://orgmode.org/worg/style/worg.css"/>
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">body{ max-width:80%; }</style>
#+INFOJS_OPT: view:showall mouse:underline path:http://orgmode.org/org-info.js home:theindex.html
```

but you can adapt it according to your needs.

Comment: This is a good method as the syntax is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own latex document classes in your .emacs file. This uses pure latex syntax and you add the definitions to the org variable `org-latex-classes`. [This blog post](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.fi/2011/04/nice-looking-pdfs-with-org-mode-and.html) explains this approach well.

In addition, I use abbrev to quickly insert org header lines to documents. 
The following lines in abbrev_devs under `org-mode-abbrev-table` make it easy to start using my custom class as well as disable header numbering and toc.

```
("oarticle" "#+LATEX_CLASS: fu-org-article" nil 0)
("otoc" "#+OPTIONS: toc:nil num:nil" nil 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want text inserted automatically when you first visit a new file, you can use the autoinsert package.  I use it for org files exactly the way you want.